# Is it possible to add a custom searchbar(via 3rd party plugin or custom) to the menu of a ready-made Wordpress Theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the Wordpress's Corporate Blue Theme, and I cant figure out a way to add a search bar to the nav(Primary Menu).

Answer (score 0):

[Ivory Search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-search-to-menu/) does exactly what you need.